# Replace words with hyperlinked word, leave hyperlinked text alone,

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of dictionary words which I load into an array.  I grab a block of text from a database table text field.

I loop through the dictionary words, and on each iteration, I check the block of text for occurrences of the word.  Whenever a match is found, I replace that word in the block with a hyperlinked version, so when the block of text is published I can hover over it with the mouse pointer and popup a definition.

This is simple to achieve with a regular expression:

```
$text = preg_replace("/($dictionary_word)/i", '<a href="" class="glossary_term">$1</a>', $text, -1, $count);
```

If I run the "dictionary word linker" more than once though, the links will be doubled up.

What I need to do is code  regular expression that detects an open anchor tag that has not been closed by the time a dictionary word is reached.  That way I will know that the word is already linked, so I skip over it.

I tried various combinations of look ahead and look behind, with no success.

Comment: So, the obvious question is, why run it more than once?

Comment: Hi Nick, if more words are added to the dictionary, I would re-run the replacement. There are a number of records each with a block of text. Also the raw text before the replacement might have other links, and I don't want to put a link inside a link.

Comment: I discovered that you cannot do a look-behind or look-ahead assertion if the pattern you are looking behind or ahead for is variable length.
i.e. you can't use '*' or '+' in the pattern you are looking behind or ahead for.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, you can just check that the matched word is not immediately followed by `</a>`:

```
"/\b($dictionary_word)\b(?!<\/a>)/i"
```

Note also the `\b` addition. This will avoid matching the `pit` in `spitting`, for example (which would turn it into `s<a ...>pit</a>ting`).

Perhaps you have other kinds of hyperlinked text in your documents? This will block all hyperlinked *single* words from being linked to the dictionary, which is appropriate since one word can't be part of two URLs. But none of this will detect words the middle of `<a href="...">a longer stretch of linked text</a>`. If you need smarter behavior, you need more than a dumb regexp-replace approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "today is 2013-04-03, tomrrow is 2013-04-04";
$output1 = preg_replace("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/i", "happy day", $str, 1);
$output2 = preg_replace("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/i", "happy day", $str);
```

replace only for once.

```
echo $output1;
today is happy day, tomrrow is 2013-04-04
```

replace all

```
echo $output2;
today is happy day, tomrrow is happy day
```

did you see the difference ?

Comment: Thanks @qqas, but my pattern can't be as specific as you demonstrated in your code.  I need to detect hyperlinked words and allow for multiple passes.  Anyway, what I have done instead is to use span tags instead of anchor tags, that way if a dictionary work appears within a hyperlink, I can still style the word and use javascript/JQuery to do the popup definitions